# Unable to extract values from object array, to which javascript array was deserialized

Tags: c#, arrays, object, serialization

```
var serializedArray = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object[]>(filter);
```

The content of the variable `filter` is `[["Title","contains","foo"],"and",["Name","contains","foo"]]`.

Content of `serializedArray` is `"object[3]","and","object[3]"`.

Content of `serializedArray[0]` is `object[3]` which are `"Title", "contains", "foo"`.

`serializedArray` can be used with index operator, and `foreach` is applicable. But not for `serializedArray[0]`.

Funny enough, both the `serializedArray` and `serializedArray[0]` have the type of `Object[].` 
What's the way to grab the value "Title" or "Name"?

Comment: I've removed the `javascript` tag. This is a question about C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           var serializedArray = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object[]>(filter);

            foreach (var item in serializedArray)
            {
               if (item is string)
               {
                  var element = item;
               }
               else
                  foreach (var innerItem in (object[])item)
                  {
                     var element = innerItem;
                  }
            }
```

Comment: Hi Jude, you have an array inside another array (nested array).  Therefore, you need an inner foreach loop inside the outer foreach loop to access elements of inner array.  It is important to cast inner array in to object[] to iterate it through inner foreach.

Comment: Missing cast to object[] inside the inner foreach got it working. Edited the answer to be accepted as the content of the variable filter coming from the UI with all those backslashes and double quotes.

Comment: **if (item is string)** check is necessary otherwise you will get exception: **Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object[]'**.   Please update your code accordingly.

Comment: OK. Normally yes, but in my case no. Cos I got another check for some other reasons `if (item.GetType() == typeof(Object[]))` which I haven't mentioned for the sake of simplicity. I re-edited.

Comment: oh ok, no problems :)